# MediaPlayer play next track from /res/raw

Tags: android, media-player

I'm making an lullaby app.Initially there are two tracks in my /res/raw folder.
On completing first track I want it to play next track.
i did this using onCompletionListener.But it is showing force close error.
Below is my code for that.
So can anyone tell me how to do that?

```
public class PlayRandom extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener{
        MediaPlayer mp;
    int rnum;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playrandom);
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lullaby1);
        mp.start();     
    }
    @Override
    public void finish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.finish();
        mp.stop();
    }
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File pdfFile = new File("res/raw/lullaby2.mp3");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        mp.stop();
        try{
            mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), path);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

---

I tried this but still its not working.
That meand there's something wrong in OnClickListener.

```
public class PlayRandom extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener{
    MediaPlayer mp;
int rnum;
TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playrandom);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lullaby1);
    mp.start();     
}
@Override
public void finish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.finish();
    mp.stop();
}
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"Yuppieee!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

use `AssetFileDescriptor`  for playing file from raw folder:

```
   AssetFileDescriptor afdes = getAssets().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.lullaby2);
    mp.reset();
    mp.setDataSource(afdes.getFileDescriptor(), afdes.getStartOffset(), afdes.getLength());
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

Comment: still its not working..!!
Actually its not going into onCompletionListener..!!

Comment: It is work on API 24+. But how to work it on version less than 23.